# File.WriteAllBytes Executes without creating File

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, writefile

I need to extract a MYSQL Db in **Mono Runtime using Xamarin Android** to a server directory using a **.NET Web API Controller Action**. Even though the code works perfectly, there were a few Android Devices that despite the fact that the Controller Action would return Success() **the MySQL Database was nowhere to be found in the Server directory**. I had to reset application data from the Device Settings in order to make it work again. Can anybody help me understand how is it possible for the controller Action to execute correctly without creating any file in that Directory?

I tried altering the code to send null instead of byte[] but the server returned a null pointer Exception

I tried altering the code to send a byte[] that only contained a single byte and it still created the appropriate file in the server Directory.

Here is the code that extracts the MySQL Database (Mono Runtime):

```
        try
        {
            var filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            var m = new MemoryStream();
            filestream.CopyTo(m);
            filestream.Close();

            return m.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong: " + e.InnerException?.Message);
        }
        return null;
```

Here is the code that processess the Extracted File. (.NET Web API Controller)

```
        try
        {
            var folder = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"E:\SQLiteBackup");
            var filename = "DB_" + AppContext.UserName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            var path = $"{folder.FullName}\\{filename}";
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, backupBytes);
            return Success();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Fail(ex, "Something went wrong");
        }
```

Comment: The code in your second snippet is invalid C#, since you redefine the `path` variable. Please post your **actual** code which actually reproduces the issue, not some code you've written especially for SO which may or may not actually demonstrate your problem

Comment: @canton7 I made the appropriate changes

Comment: Note that `Path.Combine(@"E:\SQLiteBackup", @"\DB_Thing")` results in `\DB_Thing`, not `E:\SQLiteBackup\DB_Thing` ([example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QJdxwV)). Maybe that's your problem? You need to use `"DB_" + ...` not `@"\DB_" + ...`

Comment: `var filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);`

Comment: @canton7 no this is not the problem.It was just a typo. The server path works perfectly

Comment: @Stefan I don't think this is the problem because the file exists already and if it didn't the moment it would try to read I would get an exception and hence I would be returned a null value

Comment: This is why I said you need to post your **actual** code. That's **two** "typos", which are errors introduced by you when changing the code for SO, one of them after I specifically asked you to post your actual code. For the final time, please paste your **actual** code.

Comment: @canton7 here is the actual version that's running on the server.

Comment: ... why did you originally post code which uses `Path.Combine` if your actual code doesn't call that?

Comment: Note that if you're letting the user choose their own user name, you're letting them write to any folder on your server. This is probably a security vulnerability!

Comment: Where are you getting 'backupBytes' and what's its length before you call 'WriteAllBytes'?

Comment: @HasaniH backupBytes come from the code section mentioned above in Mono runtime enviroment. The problem is that currently this code is already running on my client's server and that's the only place this error was presented.I am not able to reproduce it so I don't know the length of the backupBytes. The only thing I can be sure of is that the backupBytes are not null otherwise I would get an exception